# AWS CloudFormation, Output value from Custom Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I wanted to output a value I get form an CloudFormation Custom Resource. I'm definitely returning the value, but I wasn't sure how to reference it in an output

This is my `template.yml`:

```
Outputs:
  customresourceoutput:
    Value:
      !GetAtt creates3bucketlambda.myvalue

Resources:
  creates3bucketlambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: setups3bucket
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 300
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AmazonS3FullAccess

  Creates3BucketLoginPage:
    Type: Custom::AppConfiguration
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt creates3bucketlambda.Arn
      aOrg:
        !Ref aOrg
```

The Error I get is:

```
Failed to create the changeset: Waiter 
ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure 
state Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: resource 
creates3bucketlambda does not support attribute type myvalue in 
Fn::GetAtt
```

I'm not sure if I use a `!Sub`, `!Ref`

Comment: That's not a custom resource. That's a SAM function. "Use the `AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource` or `Custom::*String*` resource type to define custom resources in your templates."

Comment: Yes, I left out the custom resource by accident. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you can return two things from the `AWS::Serverless::Function`

```
  customresourceoutput:
    Value:
      !GetAtt creates3bucketlambda.Arn -> arn of lambda function
```

and

```
  customresourceoutput:
    Value:
      !Ref creates3bucketlambda -> name of lambda function
```

More details about serverless function outputs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#w2ab2c21c10d870c11).

If you're interested in `AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource` there is also a [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html#w2ab2c21c10d194c15) for that.

You can use `Fn::GetAtt` like:

```
  customresourceoutput:
    Value:
      !GetAtt customerResource.responseKeyName -> name of the key from the response
```

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, I needed to refer to the Custom Resource, and that would return the value I wanted...     Value: !GetAtt Creates3BucketLoginPage.key

Comment: Hi, where can I find the response key of lambda backed Custom Resource ??

Comment: Hi @ColossusMark1 in logs. How and where do you run your cloudformation?

Comment: runnning on cloudforemation wizard, I've found the responsekey, it was at the lambda response :D THANKS again